# How to make a Stochastic RSI calculate a different timeframe curve but only using math (not by changing Source)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to make a multi-timeframe Stochastic RSI but request.security() function provides a lower temporal resolution, and doesn't provide relative timeframe addressing. So I should play with its math but it doesn't work yet.

For a start, here's the current original Stoch RSI code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic RSI", shorttitle="Stoch RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```

In case of e.g. MACD, we can simply multiply its three parameters and voilà, we get the same MACD curves&histogram as if we set the Source to a particular timeframe but its nicer, it has higher temporal resolution.

**Now this "trick" doesn't work with Stochastic RSI. Curve is different, see:**
[image]
(I removed the `D` curve, to emphasize the difference. We can see and compare `K` only.

**Any idea how to modify its math to get the proper output from higher timeframes without simple changing the Source to that higher timeframe?**